# TypeError passing a commonjs 'required' function into a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, commonjs

I am using a third-party library (in node.js) that accepts a function as a parameter through a Javascript Object:

```
  exports.paths = [
  {
    path:  "foo",
    parse: function bar(parm) {
        console.log("running function");
        return;
    }
  }
```

That works fine if the function is inline, but I want to remove it to a separate file `file_b`.

```
function bar(parm) {
  console.log("running function");
  return;
}
exports.bar = bar;
```

and then require it in `file_a`:

```
var bar = require('./file_b');
exports.paths = [
  {
    path:  "foo",
    parse: bar
  }
```

Now when the third-party library tries to run my function, it gets an error: `TypeError: object is not a function`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the whole exports object. But you want to pass the property `bar`.

```
var bar = require('./file_b').bar;
```

Alternatively:

```
var bar = require('./file_b');
exports.paths = [{
    path:  "foo",
    parse: bar.bar
}]
```